# filter specific entries in an array using jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, curl, jq

i'll make this short.
This is what im dealin with. I've got a link using curl to pipe a json format output to filter specific entries using jq.
This is the json file

```
{
    "remote":  [
        {"name": "cast-1",
         "id": 1212
        },
        {"name": "cast-1",
         "id": 1214
        },
        {"name": "home-11",
         "id": 3212
        },
        {"name": "cast-3",
         "id": 3212
        },
        {"name": "cast-3",
         "id": 3213
        },
        {"name": "cast-4",
         "id": 4211
        }

    ]
}
```

my desired output is

```
 "cast-1": 1212 , 1214,
 "cast-3": 3212 , 3213,
 "cast-4": 4211,
```

with my attempt, i only am able to output this

```
 "cast-1": 1214,
 "cast-3": 3213, 
 "cast-4": 4211,
```

my code so far

```
curl ... | jq  'reduce .remote[] as $v ({}; . + {"\($v.name)":$v.id})'
```

Cant figure out to add the second id from cast-1 and cast-3.
Is there a method to format the output, to get a valid JSON output format?
maybe python or perl method? Im not familiar with awk, sed to let you know.

Comment: your desired output is not a valid JSON value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need reduce here, `group_by` should suffice. E.g:

```
.remote | group_by(.name) | map({(.[0].name): map(.id)}) | add
```

https://jqplay.org/s/_0CFADWu2G

Comment: @mogul05 I didn't understand what you said. Are you having problems invoking jq with this script?

Comment: my fault, i just fixed it. forgot to set the single quotation mark.